# Django: after form.is_valid check, cleaned_data is missing the image field

Tags: django, validation, forms, django-models

I have a form, with a bunch of fields, and then I have a:

```
    profile_image=forms.ImageField(required=False)
```

The problem si that after the form.is_valid() check,

```
form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
```

for example DOES return the actual name, however,

```
form.cleaned_data.get('profile_image')
```

DOES NOT return anynthing.

In the print(request.POST) output, i get

```
u'profile_image': [u'02 Portfolio Page.jpg']
```

but in the print(form.cleaned_data) i get:

```
 'profile_image': None
```

Why is the file lost at the is_valid check? What should I do?

UPDATE:

```
class NewChickForm(forms.Form):
first_name = forms.CharField()
last_name = forms.CharField()
profile_image=forms.ImageField(required=False)
def do_save(self):
    u = Subject(
        first_name = self.cleaned_data.get('first_name'),
        last_name = self.cleaned_data.get('last_name'),
        profile_image = self.cleaned_data.get('profile_image'),
    )
    print(self.cleaned_data)
    u.save()
    return u
```

and

```
s = Subject()
form = NewChickForm(request.POST) # 1)do i add here `request.FILES` ?
if form.is_valid():
    s = form.do_save()
            # 2) s.profile_image = form.cleaned_data.get('profile_image')?
```

Even if i do #1) and #2), i still get NONE

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure you've used the correct `enctype` on your HTML form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/foo/">
```

Also, make sure you bind `request.FILES` when you construct the form object.

```
# Bound form with an image field, data from the request
>>> f = ContactFormWithMugshot(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

[Binding uploaded files to a form](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files)

**Edit:** [File Uploads](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/)

Comment: You were right. I didn't have the multipart. added. But I am not getting the binding thing too much. The django explanation seems to be very differently done from what I have in my code. Could you drop a line on how I should be doing it according to the new code I pasted in the UPDATE? that would be really awesome

Comment: The multipart data will be put in `request.FILES`, so you need to bind it to the form in #1 for `is_valid` to validate that field.  I'm not sure about #2 as I always just extract the file from `request.FILES` directly instead of using `cleaned_data.get(...)`  Have you inspected `request.FILES` to see if your data is there?

Comment: Here, this doc is probably a better explanation: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/?from=olddocs